# How to specify limit and offset in SQL

Tags: java, sql

I am working in java. I have one table,which is having 100 rows and 2 columns. Consider the following query:-

```
String id, lastId; 
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
String query="select id from user limit 0,9";
selectStatement.execute(query);
ResultSet rs=selectStatement.getResultSet();
while(rs.next()){
    id=rs.getString(1);
    list.add(id);
}
```

---

As above, I have given limit of 10. But I want to fetch all 100 rows.So Please tell me how to start from 10 th row after iterating through 9 rows.Is there need to set id to lastId.Please give me some simple code.

Comment: You are using `MySQL`, right?

Answer (score 5):

You have given limit of `9`, not `10`.

To fetch records from 11'th to 20'th, use:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    user
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 10, 10
```

then

```
SELECT  id
FROM    user
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT 20, 10
```

and so on.

Note that you have to specify `ORDER BY` for the order of your records to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to implement paging. Did you look at the paging support available in [CachedRowSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)? (See section 10, Paging Data).

This sample code is lifted from that javadoc:

```
CachedRowSet crs = CachedRowSetImpl();
 crs.setPageSize(100);
 crs.execute(conHandle);

 while(crs.next() {
 . . . // operate on first chunk of 100 rows in crs, row by row
 }

 while(crs.nextPage()) {
     while(crs.next()) {
         . . . // operate on the subsequent chunks (of 100 rows each) in crs, 
               // row by row
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the count of rows from MySql

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user";
int count;
selectStatement.execute(query); 
ResultSet rs=selectStatement.getResultSet(); 
while(rs.next()){     
count=rs.getInt(1);     
}
```

Then iterate through the loop.

```
String id, int counter =1;
ArrayList list=new ArrayList(); 

for(int i=1; i< count/10;i++)
{
    query="select id from user limit " + i-1 +", " + (i *10)-1 ; 
    selectStatement.execute(query); 
    ResultSet rs=selectStatement.getResultSet(); 
    while(rs.next()){     
        id=rs.getString(1);     
        list.add(id); 
    }
 }
```

Since your code is in Java, there might be syntax error. Please fix them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String query="select id from user limit 0,9";

 String query="select id from user limit"+  start + "," + end;
```

Here you have hard coded the offset,limit. Instead use variables such as start, end, data_limit(10 as per example). 'start' should be start index. 'end' should be the ('start' + data_limit).